# I received blank screen in Expo Go app after installing react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native

I have installed to my RN project dependencies react-navigation/drawer, react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated. Added react-native-reanimated/plugin to babel.config.js in root directory and cleared cache.
And once without no error in terminal my Expo Go on iphone and Android just stoped working. When I press npm start in VC code it is starting sucessfully. But on the phone I just see splash screen and then it closes itself.
In console of VS code I see the error

```py
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/user/MealAppProject/package.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "768",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Problems loading reference 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults': Unable to load schema from 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults': cannot open vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults. Detail: Unable to resolve text model content for resource vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults.",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2
}]
```

But I don't know is it connected? or it's 2 separate problems.

My package.json is here

```json
{
  "name": "mealappproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.9",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've been trying to uninstall app and install again. No result.
Trying to uninstal these navigation dependacies and back to the previous config. No result. I have no idea what I can do else.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, you can solve them with,  **"close the EDI and open it again".**